# f:ajax not working with tomahawk forceId="true"

Tags: jsf-2, tomahawk

Do the JSF 2.0 f:ajax control work with the tomahawk 'forceId = true' attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The reason is f:ajax depends on clientId structure to locate the component, otherwise a full tree scanning would be necessary and that is not good for performance reasons. Instead you can use h:form prependId="false" to prevent add the id of the form. This is the accepted way to do it by JSF spec.